# Showing labels on KML map in Google Maps?

Tags: labeling, google-maps, kml

I have converted my layer, that is (from shapefile to KML) in QGIS this is the way I read it in angular:

```
this.kmlLayerc1 = new google.maps.KmlLayer ({
  url: 'http://direccion/carpeta/nombre.kml',
  map: this.map
});
```

Now, in what can I show it with its attributes as it is shown in the image.

[image]

What I have tried to do is show it that way in Google Maps, just as it is showing it with all its attributes but showing it on the map only shows the polygons and the attributes do not.

This is the image.

[image]

Any suggestions to solve it?

I convert the file .shp to .kml because that way I can show it on the map

Example, this is mi file .kml:

[image]

I just want to show the sector name as in the image

Comment: Luis, can you share your KML file so we can see if it even contains the name data that you want as labels? Depending on your export settings, QGIS may or may not include that info in the KML. That said, KML polygons cannot have labels in Google Earth, since labels only apply to Point geometries.  In Google Maps, labels like this (always shown on the map for all features) cannot be applied to either Points or Polygons, so you'll need to find another way to label all your parcels. One option is to use tooltips or info windows which can come up when a feature is clicked.

Comment: ok friend, 
I leave the structure of my file .kml

Answer (score -2):

Not possible on Google earth. You need google earth pro which is free but last I checked it was not available in Linux. That was a while back so most it may be different now. And in Google earth pro you can import shapefiles

Comment: No friend, what I did was convert my .shape file to kml in Qgis. I can already read it in angular but it does not show it to me with the labels like in Qgis

The problem is not in Google Maps or Google Earth Pro, but in showing the labels that my kml file contains in the map, as well as in the previous images.

This is a link with the same problem but I tried it but I have not had success https://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012154

Comment: Juan, sorry but that's not correct. Google Earth "Free" and Google Earth Pro are now the same thing...they were combined a while back, and all the Pro features made free.  There is now also the new Google Earth for Web, Android and iOS, but it does not have all the Pro features.  Earth Pro works just fine on Windows, Mac and Linux.